# C#4.0 Issues playing .mp3 files over 192kbps using winmm.dll

Tags: c#, audio, mp3, winmm

MCIERR_INTERNALI am trying to make a simple Media player inside an app, but I've noticed that my code WILL NOT play music unless the file is a low bitrate around 192kbps or less. The issue is that most of my music is around 260-320kbps.

Here's my code, if there's something I can do to up the 'available' bitrate options let me know, otherwise I'll need a new DLL suggestion please!

```
class MusicPlayer
{
    [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    private static extern long mciSendString(string lpstrCommand, StringBuilder lpstrReturnString, int uReturnLength, int hwndCallback);

    private static void checkMCIResult(long code)
    {
        int err = (int)(code & 0xffffffff);
        if (err != 0)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("MCI error {0}", err));
        }
    }

    public void open(string file)
    {
        string command = "open \"" + file + "\" type MPEGVideo alias MyMp3";
        checkMCIResult(mciSendString(command, null, 0, 0));
    }

    public void play()
    {
        string command = "play MyMp3";
        mciSendString(command, null, 0, 0);
    }
    public void pause()
    {
        string command = "stop MyMp3";
        mciSendString(command, null, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:
-Winform application

-using Windows 7 sp1

-Using Visulal Studio 2013 community edition

-From error catching I now see the error number is 289, -256 = 22: MCIERR_INTERNAL, not sure what that's all about

Comment: [Error number](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa228215(v=vs.60).aspx) should be 277 for MCIERROR_INTERNAL. I'm here because of the very same error 277. Also don't subtract 256. That's silly, because see link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not an inherent limitation in Windows, problems like these are environmental.  A basic check-list:

- Try this with a [known-good MP3 file](http://download.linnrecords.com/test/mp3/tone.aspx).  That test file is encoded at 320 kbps.  This helps eliminate a specific problem with your files, like a wonky DRM scheme that only permits playback on an approved player.
- Make sure you run this code on an STA thread, the kind provided by a Winforms or WPF app.  *Not* a console mode app, it requires the kind of code you find in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21684059/17034).
- Beware of having non-standard ACM drivers installed.  There is a *lot* of junk out there, always treat "codec packs" with strong distrust.  Review the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Drivers32 registry key, that's where ACM drivers are registered.
- And last but certainly not least, you are blind as a bat as long as you are ignoring the return value of mciSendString().  When it fails, it produces an error code that tells you the reason.

A simple implementation of an error checker method:

```
    private static void checkMCIResult(long code) {
        int err = (int)(code & 0xffffffff);
        if (err != 0) {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("MCI error {0}", err));
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
    public static void open(string file) {
        string command = "open \"" + file + "\" type MPEGVideo alias MyMp3";
        checkMCIResult(mciSendString(command, null, 0, 0));
    }
```

There are a lot of possible MCI errors, you'll find them listed in MMSystem.h file in the Windows SDK "include" directory on your machine.  Like C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include\MMSystem.h.  Start at MCIERR_INVALID_DEVICE_ID, subtract 256 from the error code.  Always mention your Windows and VS version btw.

Comment: thank you! I'll note I'm using Visual C# 2013 Community, This is a windows7 sp1 OS, and I am making a winform application. I'll take heed of your advise to look at what sorts of error reporting I;m getting when the files fail to play. You'll get the bounty in 21hr when I'm allowed to give it out. Thanks!

Comment: The **known-good MP3 file** solved it for me. My first test mp3 had a creative commons license. Silly world -.-

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I figured this out (thanks to @Hans Passant), the error code I was recieving was 277, Turns out there are problems with MCI and mp3's which had a large ID3(v2.x) tag - Album art, lyrics etc.

Coincidentally the 2 files causing me the trouble had album art, and completely filled out ID3 data (including Lyrics). So I'll be switching over to some other audio library for my needs

Comment: If you figured this out thanks to Hans' answer, you should mark his answer as the accepted one.  Especially since you put a bounty on it.

Comment: fair enough, I'd planned to give the bounty to him regardless.

Answer (score 0):

A typical problem with Windows API playing or not playing specific MP3 files is the following. One of the standard MP3 reading/parsing components has a [presumably?, I am under impression 16KB is in question] fixed size buffer to read initially, then skip tags and get to the real bitstream. With a lot of tags, the parser is unable to read the data and rejects the file as non-playable.

When played through DirectShow (for C# code, this would typically be playback through DirectShow.NET open source library), it is suggested to use another stock Windows component capable to read MP3 files, which is free from tag problem: Windows Media ASF Reader filter.

See related:

- [Failure to play MP3 file with COM exception in IGraphBuilder.RenderFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412073/failure-to-play-mp3-file-with-com-exception-in-igraphbuilder-renderfile)
- [Play mp3 and wav file getting error : Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040266 with RenderFile(Strfilename) on Windows 7](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b7a73b88-c63c-4b77-a02d-262eda707caf/play-mp3-and-wav-file-getting-error-exception-from-hresult-0x80040266-with?forum=windowsdirectshowdevelopment)
- [WM ASF Reader form MP3 audio playback](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.windowsmedia.sdk/5WkPgdqpZS4)

Even though it's a long standing issue, Microsoft years ago decided to not update standard MPEG-1 stream splitter and the problem basically exists in all Windows versions.

Comment: you didnt answer the question, I don't know what DirectShow is, but I was using Winmm.dll for my audio playback. This is non-helpful for me