# QMediaPlayer does not play some mp3 files

Tags: qt, audio, mp3, directshow, taglib

`QMediaPlayer` does not play a few `mp3` files.

e.g `"..\Black Star Elephant\02 Am I Wrong.mp3"` does not play but
 `..Birdy_-_Fire_Within\03 - Light Me Up.mp3"` plays.

For the file that does not play, I get the following;

`TagLib: MPEG::Header::parse() -- Invalid sample rate.` ,
`DirectShowPlayerService::doRender: Unresolved error code 80040266` and finally crashes with error `exited with code -1073741819`

I cant figure out any particular differences between the 2 files and why `Directoshow` fails for others.

Answer (score 3):

`0x80040266` is `VFW_E_NO_TRANSPORT` "Pins cannot connect due to not supporting the same transport." The problem with "non-playable" files is that they have an ID3 tag section, which is overly long for stock decoder to skip it an reach the data.

See also:

- [Failure to play MP3 file with COM exception in IGraphBuilder.RenderFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412073/failure-to-play-mp3-file-with-com-exception-in-igraphbuilder-renderfile)

Comment: Thanks. From the link, "These files will still play fine if you open them starting with WM ASF Reader Filter. This assumes you build, or at least start building, the graph manually to override default building behavior.".. how do I do this?

Comment: Yes, it assumes that you alter default graph building sequence. Since you are using a library - as it seems - you need to look up how it is doing this exactly and where you can interfere.